# I was testing some modules and their functions but when I run it, it says this:

Tags: python, python-3.9

```
    except Exception as e:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my error... I tried everything and searched for this problem far and wide, but no chance of getting the answer :(
this is the code that is creating problems:

```
except Exception as e:
print(e)
if e is "535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w131sm7041527pfd.14 - gsmtp":
    print("Maybe, you should allow less secure apps on your google accounts settings... Or, check your 
    creditials")
    speak("Maybe, you should allow less secure apps on your google accounts settings, or 
    check your creditials")
    input("Would you like me to direct you to that page? [Y/N]")
    if "Y" or "y" in query:
    webbrowser.open("https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps? 
    pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4P9nsZMthP9QP5I3QtZ4q_U0xn6Gaa2yJ4EMJpWk8Xdzuy06LknCJr6QJHe1EMfBjZ- 
    ODRg6V0Tn1X5nGUrzRvs3L-IjA")

     elif "N" or "n" in query:
     print("OK...")
     speak("OK!")
```

I don't have any idea about how do I solve it, someone help me...

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place in what you've posted.  If that is the case in the actual code, that's a likely source of your problem.  'except' needs to have the same indent as its 'try'.  You do have a 'try', don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    if e is "535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w131sm7041527pfd.14 - gsmtp":
        print("Maybe, you should allow less secure apps on your google accounts settings... Or, check your creditials")
        speak("Maybe, you should allow less secure apps on your google accounts settings, or check your creditials")
        input("Would you like me to direct you to that page? [Y/N]")
        if "Y" or "y" in query:
            webbrowser.open("https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4P9nsZMthP9QP5I3QtZ4q_U0xn6Gaa2yJ4EMJpWk8Xdzuy06LknCJr6QJHe1EMfBjZ-ODRg6V0Tn1X5nGUrzRvs3L-IjA")
            elif "N" or "n" in query:
                print("OK...")
                speak("OK!")
```

It should work for you as now is with proper indent.